MUI SwipeableDrawer leaves half open
When I try to prevent closing the drawer on swipe (based on logic) it leaves half open and does not restore its original sizes.
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

<SwipeableDrawer
    anchor="bottom"
    open={open}
    onClose={() => {
      if (logic) {
        setOpen(false)
      }
    }}
    onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
>
...
</SwipeableDrawer>

On swipe to close, if the logic is not met it leaves half open.
How I can trigger it to restore its original size if close is prevented?
Don't want to trigger it by changing its React key
MUI version: 5.6.0

I don't think it's the problem of SwipeableDrawer component or anything else. I think it's related to state management on your end.
When does the logic change?

The logic there is a confirmation dialog. The user decides if it should close

Would you log the value of logic on the console and check if it changed expectedly? I'm wondering if that value is changed during drawer is closing.

If you could move the logic from onClose handler then you could use hysteresis prop:

hysteresis (number, 0.52 by default) affects how far the drawer must be opened/closed to change its state. Specified as percent (0-1) of the width of the drawer

<SwipeableDrawer
  hysteresis={logic ? undefined : 1}
  //...

Another simple but not very elegant solution would be to let it close and then reopen it:
    onClose={() => {
      setOpen(false)
      if (!logic) {
        setTimeout(() => setOpen(true), 0);
      }
    }}

I investigated how the drawer is engineered. There is a Paper comonent in it which has CSS transform style applied to it. It's translate(0px) when the drawer is fully open and it changes as you swipe the drawer. Perhaps you could somehow get a reference to it and reset its styles, but that would make you reliant on the implementation of SwipeableDrawer component.
